# Are there any Backbone.js tutorials that teach ".sync" with the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, http, backbone.js

I read many Backbone.js tutorials, but most of them deal with static objects.

Of course, I have data on the server.  I want a tutorial that shows how backbone.js can communicate with the server to fetch data, post data, etc.

This is `.sync`, right?  I read the backbone.js documentation, but still fuzzy on how to use this feature.

Or can someone show me an example?

According to: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync

> Backbone.sync is the function that Backbone calls every time it
>   attempts to read or save a model to the server.

But when? Where do I put the function? I don't know how to use it, and the documentation doesn't give any examples. When does the data get loaded into my models? I get to define when...right?

Comment: .sync sends POST or PUT XHR requests to the server, in order to save the client model state (or GET to fetch the state from the server). It helps to look at the network traffic using the Web developer tools of your browser.

Comment: So with .sync, I don't have to use JQuery's .ajax() anymore? (to get data to my models, etc)

Comment: If the default .sync works for you, then, yes (it uses .ajax under the covers for you). If you need to change what it does, then you probably need to replace it with some code that uses .ajax directly.

Comment: @Thilo, sorry I'm just a noob. I have no idea how to use .sync. Right now, I'm using backbone.js, with .ajax() myself at random places to fetch data from the server (manually). I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The second answer below is the best: .sync is called when model.save() is called.

Comment: Good lord, it's 2014 and there are STILL no Backbone tutorials out there that cover the use of `.sync`. I stumbled my way here after two days of Google-Fu failed me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not free, but the following screencasts both have a piece on backend work and how to send data to and get data from Backbone.

1. [Tekpub](http://tekpub.com/productions/mvc3) is a 9 part screencast about asp.net MVC3, with the whole 6th part about using backbone to write an admin module to manage productions. it shows all about handling routing in MVC3 and sending & receiving data
2. Peepcode

   - http://peepcode.com/products/backbone-js about basic backbone stuff
   - http://peepcode.com/products/backbone-ii about interactivity
   - http://peepcode.com/products/backbone-iii about persistance (it's this third one you will need for server connection information).

Comment: Unfortunately the long-awaited third episode of this series, which addressed networking and persistence, suddenly switches to Coffeescript, which really limits its accessibility I think.

Comment: yes that is true, however I understand coffeescript enough to know what it is compiled into... you are absolutely right though it limits the accessability for the majority of javascript hobbyists.

Comment: @sander thanks. How come there are no "free" tutorials for Backbone.sync?

Comment: there are tutorials, but these screencasts are usually not free because they take quite some effort to build, they are not just simple screencasts of a certain feature you might get from a random developer on the net, the above screencasts are professionally made. i'm not saying others are bad, but just explaining why these are pay2view :). i cannot recall any real tutorial or screencast about the .synch(). Maybe because there are so many different back-end implementations possible, it's hard to give a good tutorial on it?

Comment: @Sander, I found this tutorial as well, which is pretty good: http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/

Comment: the tekpub content now redirects to a pluralsight 404

Answer (score 11):

You never really have to look at .sync, unless you plan to overwrite it.  For normal uses, you can simply call model.save() whenever you want and that will execute a post or put (depending on whether the record exists already).  If you want to get the data from your backend, use collection.fetch()

You'll of course also need to specify a URL, do so through your collection attribute, collection.url

Comment: This is the answer: `.sync` happens when we call `model.save()`.

Comment: @Ziggy Sure, that's when `.sync` is called, but it does not help explain the magic which is obfuscated and causing TIMEX's confusion. URLs are implicit based on the Model & that Model's respective Collection definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can override Backbones native sync functionality if you override it:

```
Backbone.sync = function() {
  //Your custom impl here
}
```

After that this function is called whenever you call a backbone function like .save() on models or .fetch() on collections. You do not have to care about data transport anymore.

I would suggest taking a look into Backbones source and look how the default sync function is implemented. Then create your own or adopt your server to support the native function.